# Tortoise SVN timestamp should sync with server's date instead of client's date

Tags: sync, tortoise-svn

We have implemented Tortoise SVN. I am facing a problem with date and time that when someone update the SVN it take date and time of client PC instead of taking server's time. So how can I get the server time ? Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't
2. You **must not rely** on timestamp *for anything*: you have more reliable and correct metrics

Comment: as it is open source there should be solution ....